# Windows Explorer - default window dimensions

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Dumb question, but I can't figure it out.

Normally, when you open an Explorer window (control + e), the window will open in a normal rectangular shape.

At some point last week, I re-arranged one of my windows to be super long and thin (900px x 100px).

Now, whatever I did (no idea) made Windows decide to magically open all new explorer windows to this retarded dimension.

This is now really getting on my nerves. How do I reset this?

(I'm running Windows 8.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close all your explorer windows until you have just one left.

Resize it to what you want and close it too.

This should remember the position for each new window.

If it doesn't, there's a way to force saving the location. Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while clicking on the [x] to close the window, and it should remember the dimensions and startup position. (works on other programs too)

Answer (score 2):

1. Resize the window to the size you want.
2. Close the window while pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

Explorer will now use the current size as the new default size.